# rails declare absolute time in a specific timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how can I get a variable which is holding always Today midnight in my timezone?

The hosting server is several hours behind me, both `Time.now.midnight` and `Date.today` are on yesterday date for good part of the day.

Thanks

Comment: Is it fair game to set the `TZ` environment variable before starting your application? Or do you want to change the timezone potentially many times while the program is running, from within the application?

Comment: the app is a backend service, so each time it is called, it should consider the midnight of the "caller" timezone. Practically, calling the function now from Japan should consider 04-Feb, from US 03-Feb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
now=DateTime.now
 => Fri, 03 Feb 2012 21:57:21 EST -05:00 

now.in_time_zone('London').midnight
=> Sat, 04 Feb 2012 00:00:00 GMT +00:00 

now.in_time_zone('Hawaii').midnight
=> Fri, 03 Feb 2012 00:00:00 HST -10:00
```